# Problem 17 chapter 4 from baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be real function defined on $(a,b)$. Prove that the set of points at which $f$ has a discontinuity of first kind is at most countable.

**Proof:** Let $E$ be the set of points at which $f$ has a discontinuity of first kind. Then $E=E_1\sqcup E_2\sqcup E_3\sqcup E_4$ where $$E_1=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^1: f(x-)<f(x+)\}, \quad E_2=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^1: f(x-)>f(x+)\},$$ $$E_3=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^1: f(x-)=f(x+)>f(x)\},\quad E_4=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^1: f(x-)=f(x+)<f(x)\}.$$
We'll consider the set $E_1$. Exists $p\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x-)<p<f(x+).$

Assume that $f(x-)=\alpha<p$ then for $\varepsilon=p-\alpha$ $\exists \delta>0$ such that for all $t\in (x-\delta,x)$ implies that $|f(t)-\alpha|<p-\alpha$ $\Rightarrow$ $-p+2\alpha<f(t)<p$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(t)<p$. Then exists $q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap(x-\delta,x)$ such that $a<q<t<x$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(t)<p$. Repeating above reasoning we get that exists $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<t<r<b$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(t)>p$.

Thus for any $x\in E_1$ we associate triple $(p,q,r)\in \mathbb{Q}^3$.
It's easy to check that this mapping is *injective*.

We'll consider the set $E_3$. Exists $p\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x-)=f(x+)>p>f(x).$
Repeating above reasoning we get that exists $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $a<q<t<x$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(t)>p$. Also exists $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $x<t<r<b$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(t)>p$.

Thus for any $x\in E_3$ we associate triple $(p,q,r)\in \mathbb{Q}^3$.
It's easy to check that this mapping is *injective*.

**Remark:** Similar reasoning for $E_2$ and $E_4$.

We have mapping $\varphi: E_1\to \mathbb{Q}$ and we *can restrict* this map to $S=\varphi(E_1)$ and we get $\varphi:E\to S\subset \mathbb{Q}$ which is injective and surjective and we know that $S$ is at most countable. Hence $E_1$ is at most countable. We get that $E_j$, $j=\overline{1,4}$ are at most countable. Then $E=E_1\sqcup E_2\sqcup E_3\sqcup E_4$ also is at most countable. Q.E.D.

Please can anyone check this and answer is this proof correct?

Comment: Can anyone check this please?